# How to run asp .net core api on port 5003?

Tags: c#

I need to run my asp.net core api on port 5003, how to do this? (port 5000 is already in used by another asp.het core api)

I am facing with : : Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in used

below is my launchSettings.json

```
{
    "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5003",
      "sslPort": 5002
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
     "myapp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5003;https://localhost:5002",
      "environmentVariables": {
       "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

and my startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseHsts();

        app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                 template: "{controller}/{action}");
        });
```

Comment: All the URLs seem to have port 5003 already. What's the problem?

Comment: I am facing with : Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in used

Comment: That's for port 5000. What about 5003?

Comment: it looks like it keeps using port 5000

Comment: by the way, I am using centOS 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it with [UseUrls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2#server-urls)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseUrls("http://*:5003");
```

Comment: where to put that?

Comment: @Donald in your Program.cs

Comment: it is running now, but I still unable to access it?

503 - Service Unavailable